# Get one element from an ItemsControl and binding to a Button

Tags: wpf

I have an ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="myList" ItemTemplateSelector="{DynamicResource mySelectorTemplate}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource myPanelTemplate}"/>
```

I want to take one of the items and make a button with his logic:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource myButtonStyle}"/>
```

One of the items of myList has a boolean with true value. This is the item with which the button will be made:

```
Private myCollection As ObservableCollection(Of Items.Subitems)

myList.ItemsSource = myCollection
```

When myCollection.myBooolean = true, is the field that gives to the item this special treatment.

What would be an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilitys for this - but this looks like the best way.

You want to use a `DataTemplateSelector`. You can choose n `DataTemplate`s with this by your own `overwritten` logic.

***C#***

Sample Class:

```
public class MySampleClass
{
        public string Name;

        public bool MyFlag;
}
```

Sample Template Selector

```
    public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {

        public DataTemplate IsTrueTemplate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public DataTemplate IsFalseTemplate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }


        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            MySampleClass temp = item as MySampleClass;

            if(temp != null)
            {
                if (temp.MyFlag)
                {
                    return IsTrueTemplate;
                }
                else
                {
                    return IsFalseTemplate;
                }

                // And so on
            }
            else
            {
                return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage in XAML

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
        <example:MyTemplateSelector>
            <example:MyTemplateSelector.IsTrueTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource myButtonStyle}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </example:MyTemplateSelector.IsTrueTemplate>
            <example:MyTemplateSelector.IsFalseTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </example:MyTemplateSelector.IsFalseTemplate>
        </example:MyTemplateSelector>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
</ListBox>
```

`example` is your DataTemplateSelector-Namespace.
I would recommend you - to store the `DataTemplates` in the Resources and set it via `StaticResource`.