# WPF conditional context menu selector

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

We have a rendered 3D model in a certain control, and we would like to open a context menu when right clicking on the model.
However, when right clicking on the background we'd like a different context menu to open.

Right now I've implemented a control with two context menu properties, that checks whether the pixel clicked on is black (background) or not.

We'd like to have another property that accepts a property/command of the view model that gets the x,y coordinates and returns what type of context menu should be opened.
Any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of many ways for your problem - Use a `DataTemplateSelector`.

Check out my comments in the `XAML`

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyleSelector>
                <!-- Nice I can have different ContainerStyles now depending on the context-->
            </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyleSelector>
            <ContextMenu.ItemContainerTemplateSelector>
                <!-- Nice I can have different Templates now for the content on the items depending on the context -->
            </ContextMenu.ItemContainerTemplateSelector>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.ContextMenu>        
</Grid>
```

Check this answer out  - here is descriped [How to use a Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996195/get-one-element-from-an-itemscontrol-and-binding-to-a-button/43996784#43996784)